# Java constructor of a subclass of an abstract class

Tags: java, abstract-class

I started to develop my first java project, it's a kind of basic roleplaying game. I want to create a character.

First I'll explain a few things:

- `Game` class - gets character class input (like Fighter).
- `Character` - has all the character data.
- `CharacterClass` - abstract class that includes information for each character class (like `Fighter`).
- `Fighter` (and other classes) extends the abstract class `CharacterClass`, should set initial stats for the chosen character class (like `Fighter`).

What I want to do is choose a character class in `Game` (let's assume that I choose `Fighter`), and get all the stats by `displayStats`. When the character chooses a class then `Game` should call something like: `Chracter ch = new Character(name, scan)`, and then `ch.displayCharacter`.

My problem is `Fighter`'s constructor and assigning this data to `Character`'s constructor.

```
public class Game {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println("Choose a character: ");
    System.out.println("1. Fighter");
    System.out.println("2. Rogue");
    System.out.println("3. Mage");
    System.out.println("4. Cleric");


    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int scan = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Character Class: " + CharacterUtil.getCharacterClass(scan));

    System.out.println("Choose Name:");
    Scanner nameIn = new Scanner(System.in);
    String name = nameIn.next();
    System.out.println("Name: " + name);

}
}


public class Character {

private String name;
private String characterClass;
private int level;
private int hp;
private int currentHp;
private long xp;
/*private int BAB; /*Base attack bonus*/

private int strength;
private int constitution;
private int dexterity;
private int intelligence;
private int wisdom;
private int charisma;

Character(String name, String chracterClass){

    this.name = name;
    this.characterClass = chracterClass;
    level =  ;
    hp = ;
    currentHp = hp;
    xp = 0;
    strength = ;
    constitution = ;
    dexterity = ;
    intelligence = ;
    wisdom = ;
    charisma = ;


}


void displayCharacter(){
    System.out.println("Name: " + name);
    System.out.println("Level: " + level);
    System.out.println("Class: " + characterClass);
    System.out.println("HP: " + hp);
    System.out.println("Attributes: ");
    System.out.println("Strength: " + strength);
    System.out.println("Constitution: " + constitution);
    System.out.println("Dexterity: " + dexterity);
    System.out.println("Intelligence: " + intelligence);
    System.out.println("Wisdom: " + wisdom);
    System.out.println("Charisma: " + strength);
    System.out.println("XP: " + xp);

}

}
```

---

```
abstract class CharacterClass {

private int level;
private int hp;

private int strength;
private int constitution;
private int dexterity;
private int intelligence;
private int wisdom;
private int charisma;

CharacterClass(){

    level = 1;
    hp = 10;
    strength = 10;
    constitution = 10;
    dexterity = 10;
    intelligence = 10;
    wisdom = 10;
    charisma = 10;
}
```

---

```
class Fighter extends CharacterClass {

Fighter(){
    super.level = 1;
    super.hp = 10;
    super.strength = 16;
    super.constitution = 14;
    super.dexterity = 14;
    super.intelligence = 10;
    super.wisdom= 10;
    super.charisma = 10;
}
}
```

Comment: Can you give us more details on the problem? I don't really understand what you mean by "My problem is Fighter's constructor and assigning this data to Character's constructor."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either make your CharacterClass private fields protected instead of private so they can be accessed by subclasses or implement getters/setters in your abstract class and use them in your subclass constructor.

Also super.field does not mean anything : your are instanciating an object which will have the fields from the abstract class and the subclass, it will be this.fields that you want to access.

Sample code :

```
public abstract class CharacterClass {

    private int intelligence;
    private int strength;
    private int dexterity;
    private int vitality;

    protected CharacterClass() {
        setIntelligence(10);
        setStrength(10);
        setDexterity(10);
        setVitality(10);
    }

    public int getDexterity() {
        return dexterity;
    }
    protected void setDexterity(int dexterity) {
        this.dexterity = dexterity;
    }
    public int getVitality() {
        return vitality;
    }
    protected void setVitality(int vitality) {
        this.vitality = vitality;
    }
    public int getStrength() {
        return strength;
    }
    protected void setStrength(int strength) {
        this.strength = strength;
    }
    public int getIntelligence() {
        return intelligence;
    }
    protected void setIntelligence(int intelligence) {
        this.intelligence = intelligence;
    }

}
```

---

```
public class Fighter extends CharacterClass {

    public Fighter() {
        setStrength(15);
        setVitality(15);
    }

}
```

---

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CharacterClass player = new Fighter();

        System.out.println(player.getStrength());
        System.out.println(player.getIntelligence());
    }

}
```

This will print 15 followed by 10, because the strength has been modified by figther, but the intelligence is still the one defined in CharacterClass.

Note that you probably want your player to be more than a CharacterClass or a Figther. While you will have a lot of Figther, Rogues and Mages as PNJs, the player will have a whole other range of possibilities, like storing items in his inventory, interacting with the world, etc.

Good luck with your game !

Comment: I prefer to keep it as private. I'll add getters/setters in my abstract class. Then I'll use setters in Fighter. I'll need to create an object (a subclass of CharacterClass, like Fighter, according to the input)  in Character, and use getters for Character's constructor. right ? Have I missed something ?

Comment: Right, it should be this rather than super.

Comment: @Niminim No that's it, although it could be more natural if your Character itself extended Fighter : I believe it would be more natural to access Character.getStrength() rather than Character.getCharacterClass().getStrength()

Comment: @Niminim probably a typo but it's setters you should be using in your Fighter class' constructor. Let CharacterClass' constructor set default values and use its setters in Figther to override some of them. If you don't need to override values then there is nothing to do, CharacterClass' constructor already set them for your figther.

Comment: I discussed the issue of Character as an abstract class here (that's what I thought in the beginning), but some people here pointed out that a character has character class rather than a character is a character class. So aggregation is probably better if a character has more than one character class. Though you're right, it would be easier to access if fighter will extend CharacterClass.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Aaron :)

Comment: Fighter(){
       level = CharacterClass.setLevel(1); doesn't work, it says that level is private in CharacterClass. Any idea why ?

Comment: @Niminim what you might be missing is the fact that when you instanciate a Figther, it first executes the CharacterClass constructor then the Figther Constructor, and that both work on a same object : your resulting player. So while you can't use this.strength in the Fighter class, using it  in the CharacterClass does modify your Figther stats, in the same way using setStrength() in the Figther class' constructor will do. I hope the example code will make everything clear :)

Comment: You're welcome ! I hope you will learn much more in the process of making your game, good luck ! :)

Comment: Just one last problem -  We just know scan (the input, which is a string, let's say "Fighter"), we don't know that we want to create a Fighter object. CharacterClass player = new Fighter(); How can we fix this ? Maybe casting or something like that can help ?

Comment: @Niminim I think you should use switch (or a regular if/else if) to create the appropriate object depending on the user input. You might want to first declare a CharacterClass variable but only affect it the desired object in the switch : `CharacterClass player; switch(userChoice) : case "figther" : player = new Figther(); [...]` not too sure about the switch / case syntax, you should check it out.

Comment: I thought maybe there's a more elegant solution than using switch, but if there's no other choice then I'll use switch. Thanks !